# Given an integer $n>0$, how many non-ordered triplets satisfy $abc=n$?

Tags: combinatorics

My best approach yet is to distinguish if $n$ is even or odd. If it is odd, then surely $a$,$b$ and $c$ are odd. If it is even, from its prime factorization we can see that we have $n = 2^m\big(\frac{n}{2^m}\big)$ for a particular $m>0$, so either $a=\big(\frac{n}{2^m}\big)$ and $bc=2^m$, or $a=2^m$ and $bc=\big(\frac{n}{2^m}\big)$.

Comment: I would start with $n=p^m$ where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890989/) includes a simple memoized recurrence to compute this statistic (non-ordered).