# How many set of size $m$ integers such that the product is $n$

Tags: combinatorics, prime-factorization

This question is related to optimizing the amount of computations of a program.

How many sets of $m$ naturals can be formed such that their product equals the number $n$ ?

Here is what I tried

Let $\prod_{i=1}^\ell p_i^{k_i}$ be the prime factorization of $n$. Then we want to distribute the $k_i$ $p_i$s to the $m$ numbers in the set for every $i$. What we can do is making a [list of $k_i$ stars and $m-1$ bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and choosing the placement of the $m-1$ bars among this list, this gives me ${k_i+m-1\choose m-1}$ ways of choosing how to dispatch the $k_i$ $p_i$s to those $m$ numbers.

Then I multiply all these for any $i$ and since I don't care about rearrangement of the $m$ numbers. So my answer is

$$\frac{1}{m!} \prod_{i=1}^\ell {k_i+m-1\choose m-1},$$

which unfortunately is not necessarily an integer and doesn't match what I found manually. Does any of you have an idea ?

Comment: Example: $m=3, n =6$. Then the set $\{1,1,6\}$ only has 3 rearrangements, while $\{1,2,3\}$ has all 6 kinds.

Comment: This [MSE link I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890989/) might be relevant, as might be this [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866418/). These statistics have basic recurrences.