# Distributing colored balls into bins such that each bin is distinct.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Suppose I have $n = n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_k$ balls of $k$ colors, with exactly $n_i \geq 1$ balls of color $i$. Balls that are the same color are indistinguishable. Additionally, we have $m$ indistinguishable bins. I would like to count the number of ways in which we can distribute the balls over all bins such that each bin is non-empty, and no two bins have the exact same multiset of balls (i.e. we can not have two bins $\{R, B\}$, but we can have both of the bins $\{R, B\}$ and $\{R, R, B\}$).

Example: say we have $m=2$ and $n_1 = 3$ ('red') and $n_2 = 2$ ('blue'). Then the valid distributions are:

- $\{\{R, R, R, B\}, \{B\}\}$
- $\{\{R, R, R\}, \{B, B\}\}$
- $\{\{R, R, B, B\}, \{R\}\}$
- $\{\{R, R, B\}, \{R, B\}\}$
- $\{\{R, R\}, \{R, B, B\}\}$

So the answer is $5$ (modulo an overseen distribution on my part :-) ).

How can I compute this quantity for given $n_1,n_2, \dots, n_k$ and $m$?

Comment: Oh god...the distinct bin condition is rough.

Comment: Yes, it is. FYI this isn't a problem from a text book or anything, it might not have a nice solution.

Comment: If not for that condition, this problem has a relatively clean solution. I'm not convinced that as written, it does. You probably have to do some major inclusion-exclusion work.

Comment: Yes, then it is a standard problem. I was trying to do inclusion/exclusion over that but it doesn't become very pretty. I was hoping someone here had a good idea on how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

Note:   what   follows   is   a  close   adaptation   of   this   [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866418),  which treats
unique factorizations of  integers into multisets of  factors.  In the
present problem the factors have to  be unique.  Suppose we start with
the source multiset and using the notation from the cited link

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\prod_{k=1}^l A_k^{\tau_k}$$

where we  have $l$ different  values and their multiplicities  are the
$\tau_k.$

If we  have a  CAS like Maple,  $N$ is reasonable  and we  seek fairly
instant computation  of these values  then we  may just use  the cycle
index  $Z(P_N)$ of  the unlabeled  operator $\textsc{SET}_{=N}.$  This
yields the formula

$$\left[\prod_{k=1}^l A_k^{\tau_k}\right]
Z\left(P_N; -1 + \prod_{k=1}^l \frac{1}{1-A_k}\right).$$

Here we have used the recurrence by Lovasz for the quoted cycle index,
which is

$$Z(P_N) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{l=1}^N (-1)^{l-1} a_l Z(P_{N-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(P_0) = 1.$$

Maple can extract these coefficients  by asking for the coefficient of
the corresponding Taylor series.  We get the following transcript:

```
> MSETS([3,2], 2);                                          
                             5

> map(el->el[1], select(el->el[\                            
> 2]>0, [seq([n, FACTORS(n,3)], n=1..256)]));           
[24, 30, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, 56, 60, 64, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80,

    84, 88, 90, 96, 100, 102, 104, 105, 108, 110, 112, 114,

    120, 126, 128, 130, 132, 135, 136, 138, 140, 144, 150,

    152, 154, 156, 160, 162, 165, 168, 170, 174, 176, 180,

    182, 184, 186, 189, 190, 192, 195, 196, 198, 200, 204,

    208, 210, 216, 220, 222, 224, 225, 228, 230, 231, 232,

    234, 238, 240, 246, 248, 250, 252, 255, 256]
```

The sequence is [OEIS  A122181](https://oeis.org/A122181) and looks to
have the  right values. The Maple  code here is quite  simple and also
includes a  recurrence that does not  use PET, which is  based on [MSE
Link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890989/).

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*
           add((-1)^(l-1)*a[l]*pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subsl, polyvars, indvars, v, pot;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    subsl := [];

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subsl := [op(subsl), v=subs(subs1, poly)];
    od;

    subs(subsl, ind);
end;


MSETS :=
proc(src, N)
local msetgf, cind, gf, cf;

    msetgf := mul(1/(1-A[q]), q=1..nops(src))-1;
    cind := pet_cycleind_set(N);

    gf := pet_varinto_cind(msetgf, cind);

    for cf to nops(src) do
        gf := coeftayl(gf, A[cf] = 0, src[cf]);
    od;

    gf;
end;

FACTORS :=
proc(n, N)
local mults;

    mults := map(el -> el[2], op(2, ifactors(n)));
    MSETS(mults, N);
end;

FACTREC :=
proc(val, numel, maxfact)
option remember;
local divs;

    if numel = 1 then
        return `if`(1 < val and val <= maxfact, 1, 0);
    fi;

    divs := select(d -> d <= maxfact, divisors(val));
    add(FACTREC(val/d, numel-1, d-1), d in divs);
end;

FACTORSX := (n, N) -> FACTREC(n, N, n);
```