# How to calculate the number of set partitions of an arbitrary set?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, set-partition

Pre-Amble

I would like to rephrase the question

PREVIOUS INSTANCE OF THIS QUESTION ( Was closed due to an alleged duplicity ).

Considering sets of four elements we can consider sets of the following type:

- ABCD,
- AACD,
- AADD,
- AAAD,
- AAAA.

The number of types is (of course) equal to p(4)=5, where p(n) is
the PartitionsP (MMa) function.

The number of set partitions for these type of sets is:

- ABCD: 15 = BellB[4] (MMa), where BellB is the Bell Number Function
- AACD: 11
- AADD: 9
- AAAD: 7
- AAAA: 5.

The 7 set partitions of AAAD are

- AAAD (1)
- AA, AD (2)
- AAD, A (2)
- AAA, D (2)
- AA, A, D (3)
- AD, A, A (3)
- A, A, A, D (4).

I would like to know the number of set partitions of an arbitrary set, for example:
ABCDEF (although, for this particular case, BellB[6] works),
AAAFFF, or
AAAAAA,
expressed in a formula, or a (programmable) algorithm.

( The Function SetPartitions in the Combinatorica Package in Mathematica can calculate the actual partitions but is rather memory-consuming, even for moderate set sizes. )

Comment: You talk about random sets, but you don't specify a probability distribution. I get the impression that what you actually mean is *arbitrary* sets?

Comment: Thank you very much, good point, I will change this in the text.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/771265) answer your question?

Comment: Certainly not directly, but it might be a start, or at least a hint. I will study, and test, both question and answer first. - Thanks for your reply. - If you think this Q. should be closed as a duplicate, then where is the answer in the duplicate? How many partitions are there in a set of type AAABBBCDEFGH ?

Comment: When there are only two types of objects, the number of partitions is in [OEIS A054225](http://oeis.org/A054225).

Comment: Not a duplicate of 771265. That question requires that each partition has at most one of every value, but this one allows the partitions to have any multiplicities.

Comment: I will solve this somehow.

Comment: @joriki Confusing random for arbitrary is due to the fact that my native language is Dutch. In my country they think it is a simple thing to change the language at universities from Dutch to English. Just to get more foreign students. - They haven't got a clue about how sensitive the English language is, especially in Mathematics.